# Trying to make a phone book using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a phone book using these instructions

> Write a program that creates 2 lists: one of names and one of phone numbers. Give these variables appropriate names (for example names and numbers). Using a for loop, have the user enter 3 names and 3 numbers of people for the phone book.  Next: display the entries from the phone book, name and then number. Use a for loop. Next, ask the user to enter a name. Store their input in a variable. Use a search to see if the name is entered in the name list. If the name is in the name list, print the number. If not have the program respond, “Name not found.

Your output should look like:

```
Name Number
sally 11 
bob 22 
carl 33   
Number you are looking for is: 11
```

All I want to know is how do you make a simple list out of user inputed data. so I can do this question.

```
Pseudocode is 
#LOOP THREE TIMES
# names = GET INPUT name
# numbers = GET INPUT number
#END LOOP

#LOOP THREE TIMES
# PRINT (name) in names, (number) in numbers
#END LOOP

# searchName = GET INPUT "Enter a name for Search"
#IF searchName IN names THEN
# PRINT matching number
# LOOP names
# IF searchName == name THEN
# foundIndex = name(index)
# searchPhoneNumber = phoneNumber[foundIndex]
# END IF
# END LOOP
# PRINT searchPhoneNumber
#ELSE
# PRINT "Name Not Found"
#END IF
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include whatever  python code you have, even if it's wrong. We're not going to do your homework for you

Comment: use the dictionary to do this

Comment: @hadi dictionary _might_ be a better choice but in question text it is specifically stated to use two lists.

Comment: This is not home work, it is something I am trying to learn on my own. My sister and I are trying to learn this through a program we have, We can do everything else we just do not remember how to convert a users entered numbers into a list. but thank you.

Comment: We do  not have the list yet and are trying to take some inputted data (numbers) and convert them into a list.

Comment: create empty lists and then use the append function as I detailed below in a loop.  An empty list looks like this: namelist=[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
names = []
phone_numbers = []
num = 3


for i in range(num):
    name = input("Name: ")
    phone_number = input("Phone Number: ") # for convert to int => int(input("Phone Number: "))

    names.append(name)
    phone_numbers.append(phone_number)

print("\nName\t\t\tPhone Number\n")

for i in range(num):
    print("{}\t\t\t{}".format(names[i], phone_numbers[i]))

search_term = input("\nEnter search term: ")

print("Search result:")

if search_term in names:
    index = names.index(search_term)
    phone_number = phone_numbers[index]
    print("Name: {}, Phone Number: {}".format(search_term, phone_number))

else:
    print("Name Not Found")
```

Answer (score 2):

To add a name or number to the appropriate list, use the append function i.e.

```
numberlist.append(number_that_was_input)
```

or

```
namelist.append(name_that_was_input)
```

and as @cricket007 so eloquently states, we do like to see that you at least try to do things for yourself.

Comment: I thank you for your comments and I am not asking for all of it for we have that mostly done it is just the numbers part we are having a problem with. This is a subject that my sister and I are trying to learn so that when we take the class  in the fall we will have a jump on it. thank you, though.

Comment: I understand how to add to a list but how do you make the list in the first place from users numbers,

Answer (score 0):

To receive input from the user, use the `input()` function.

Example:

```
name = input('type in name')
print(name)
#Outputs the name you typed.
```

To add that value into a list use the `append`.

Example:

```
my_list = [] #Initialize list first.
my_list.append(name) # this will add the contents of variable name to your list.
# my_list now looks like this: ["user817205"]
```

Since you have to do this 3 times, it's smart to use a `for` loop to do that,
you can iterate 3 times through a block of code using the following:

```
for _ in range(3):
    #type the code you want to repeat 3 times here!
```

PS.: Remember you only need to initialize your list once, so keep the `my_list = []` out of the for loop.